# Use two completely different classes as one

Tags: database, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have very stupid question about design patterns: let's say we have two classes `Post` and `Product`, for each of them we have different table in the DB, and they have nothing in common with each other, so we can't create base class for them. Some `Posts` even **contains** `Products`. And here's what we should do with them:

1. Somehow store `Post` and `Product` instances in the DB, pack them in one array(using C++, if it matters) when user requests news feed from the next item, send it to the client, and receive and unpack on the client side(using Java).
2. Next, we have to show both `Post` and `Product` in the **one list**(such as news feed on the Facebook).
3. Also, we can share `Post` or `Product` with our friends using chat. So we can send `Post` or `Product` as an attachment of the message(consequently, we should to store id of sent `Post` or `Product` in the column `attached_item` of  the `messages` table in the DB on the server side).

So, what design pattern would be best here? How should I implement the `Post` and `Product` classes?

Comment: Well, they have things in common, they can both be in a list, both can be shared and both can be sent as an attachment. You might want interfaces for these. For the rest it is really a broad question. Also you need to use composition as Posts should have a list of Products.

Comment: @Bentaye ok, but how should they be stored in the DB? And what do you think should be this interface? Should it be just dummy or something more useful?

Comment: Keep 3 tables: POSTS, PRODUCTS and MAP_POST_PRODUCTS. When a post contains a product, then you put the mapping into the MAP_POST_PRODUCTS table.

Comment: @fusiled this is ok, but what about `messages` table and column for the attached items from the my 3 item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very broad question, but here is a skeleton of what you could you, just to give you some ideas:

```
// An interface containing methods specific to objects you can list
interface Listable {}

// An interface containing methods specific to objects you can share
interface Shareable {}

// An interface containing methods specific to objects you can send
interface Sendable {}

class Post implements Listable, Shareable, Sendable {
    List<Product> products;
}

class Product implements Listable, Shareable, Sendable {
}


class ListManager {
    public void addToList(Listable element) { }
}

class ShareManager {
    public void share(Shareable element) { }
}

class SendManager {
    public void send(Sendable element) { }
}
```

You could then use `Post` and `Product` interchangeably this way:

```
Post post = new Post();
Product product = new Product();

ListManager listManager = new ListManager();
listManager.addToList(post);
listManager.addToList(product);

ShareManager shareManager = new ShareManager();
shareManager.share(post);
shareManager.share(product);

SendManager sendManager = new SendManager();
sendManager.send(post);
sendManager.send(product);
```

Regarding the database representation, as suggested `fusiled` in his comment, just stick them in 2 separate tables. With a mapping table in between to link the products to their post.

**EDIT**
Regarding the issue with the MESSAGES table

You could add a new mapping table MESSAGE_ATTACHED_ITEM with columns `messageId`, `postId`, `productId`. Only set a value to the relevant colum when attaching an item to a message

Or an other option would be to have an ATTACHED_ITEM table with an id only.
And have Post and Product tables to have a foreign key to this table Id. 
you can then stick this attachedItemId into your attached_item column

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood your idea. But we still have issue with the `messages` table and column for the attached items from the my 3 item in the question, what we should do with this?

Comment: @don-prog I don't understand your problem, you already said that you would store the id of the Post or Product attached to the message in the `attached_item` of the MESSAGES table. What more do you want to know about that?

Comment: Sorry, if it was not clear, I meant that we somehow should to store `id` of sent `Post` or `Product` in the column `attached_item` of the `messages` table. But how can we do this, if `Post` and `Product` - different types and different tables in the DB?

Comment: @don-prog Right, you are worried that you could have a same id for both a Post and a Product? What about adding a column `attached_item_type` with value `post` or `product` so you know in what table to look it up

Comment: @don-prog An other solution, if you haven't started the project yet and have no data in the tables yet, would be to have the Ids of Post and Product being taken from a same database sequence so they would be unique

Comment: I already thought about that option, but what about foreign keys? The column can't refer to two different tables.

Comment: @Then what about a MESSAGE_ATTACHED_ITEM table with columns messageId, postId, productId? only one of the 2 former Ids having a value, the other one remaining NULL

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution could be simpler than you think. Why don't you ust use a common `Java`-like interface and hide the implementation details?

Just implement a common interface with the methods you need. Supposing this common interface is called `EntityInterface`:

```
public class Post implements EntityInterface {};
public class Product implements EntityInterface {};
```

Then when you want to handle these classes, you treat them as an `EntityInterface` object:

```
EntityInterface myNewPost = new Post();
EntityInterface myNewProduct = new Product();
//Now you see myNewProduct and myNewPost as EntityInterface objects
```

These code fragments are in `Java`, but use virtual functions in `C++` and you get the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we still have issue with the `messages` table and column for the attached items from the my 3 item, what we should do with this?